# unable to add fonts in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-test

I am trying to add custom fonts in my flutter app. I have added fonts in pubspec.yaml

```
flutter:
  fonts:
    - family: Quicksand
      fonts:
        - asset: assets/fonts/Quicksand-Regular.ttf
```

Aslo I have added this in my Text widget

```
style: TextStyle(
           color: Colors.white,
           fontSize: 80.0,
           fontFamily: 'Quicksand',
           ),
```

I am not getting any error, but my font is not getting applied.

Comment: you are using family name - Quicksand in pubspec.yaml why use name - 'Roboto' in code- use Quicksand instead.

Comment: I have tried both, it's not working

Comment: make sure you re-build the project again after adding in pubspec.yaml - hot restart wont work. Also do run - flutter packages get

Comment: Wow, I rebuild it and it's working now,
Thanks man...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure you Re-Build the Project Again - Hot-Restart Won't work & do run `flutter packages get`

Comment: Yeah. It's the same truly for any kind of assets. If you add some image, font, sound, etc. on the fly you need to re-run the full application.

Answer (score 0):

when you add the font to youre project. first, you must restart your app after that its work normally .its important not using Hot Reload in this case! for the first time